# JS should select the second option where we have used selected="selected"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select class="some_flex_select">
        <option value="con_1">One</option>
        <option value="con_2" selected="selected">Two</option>
        <option value="con_3">Three</option>
</select>
```

JS →

```
select.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  if (event.target.value === 'con_2') {
    classTwo.classList.add('class_2')
}else if (event.target.value === 'con_3') {
    classTwo.classList.add('class_3')
}else if (event.target.value === 'con_1') {
    classTwo.classList.remove('class_3', 'class_2')
}
})

// Do the check initially...
checkSelect()
// ... and on change events
select.addEventListener('change', checkSelect)
```

My expectations are that the default is con_2, and the JS should implement that class by default, but that is not happening.

Comment: what is the code you have written in ```checkselect()```?

Comment: I dont know aht to write. can you please guide me?

Comment: You should try to implement your requirement on plunker or somewhere else and then share it with others mentioning what worked & what didn't. It will help others to understand your issue. Your current description is actually too confusing

Comment: what was the issue in my code? can you please help understanding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. I have tested this here →
https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/jKzqrx

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select') // use more specific selector here
var classTwo = document.querySelector('.flex_parent')

function checkSelect () {
  if (select.value === 'con_2') {
     classTwo.classList.add('flex_parent_2')
 }else if (select.value === 'con_3') {
     classTwo.classList.add('flex_parent_3')
 }else if (select.value === 'con_1') {
     classTwo.classList.remove('flex_parent_3', 'flex_parent_2')
 }
}
checkSelect();
select.addEventListener('change', checkSelect)
```

```css
.flex_parent {color: blue; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold}
.flex_parent_2 {color: red; font-size: 25px;}
.flex_parent_3 {color: green; font-size: 25px;}
```

```html
    <select class="video_home_flex_select">
        <option value="con_1">Blue </option>
        <option value="con_2" selected="selected">Red</option>
        <option value="con_3">Green</option>
    </select>

<div class="flex_parent">
   Hey I am changing color!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```js
 $('select').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value === 'con_2') {
            classTwo.classList.add('class_2')
      }else if (this.value === 'con_3') {
            classTwo.classList.add('class_3')
      }else if (this.value === 'con_1') {
            classTwo.classList.remove('class_3', 'class_2')
     }
      alert( this.value );
    })
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select class="video_home_flex_select">
                <option value="con_1">One</option>
                <option value="con_2" selected="selected">Two</option>
                <option value="con_3">Three</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Not posisble with vanilla JS?

Comment: actually i put it for test purpose

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select class="some_flex_select" onchange="checkSelect(this.value)">
<option  id="con_1" value="con_1">One</option>
<option id="con_2" value="con_2" >Two</option>
<option id="con_3" value="con_3">Three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var defult_id='con_2';
document.getElementById(defult_id).selected = "true";

function checkSelect(selected){

  if (selected === 'con_2') {
    //add class
//classTwo.classList.add('class_2');
}else if (selected === 'con_3') {
//classTwo.classList.add('class_3');
}else if (selected === 'con_1') {
//classTwo.classList.remove('class_3', 'class_2');
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: You are not injecting the classes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for-

```js
myselect = document.getElementById("myselect");

function checkSelect(event) {
  var option = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
  switch (option) {
    case "con_2":
      alert("con_2 selected");
      //classTwo.classList.add('class_2');
      break;
    case "con_3":
      alert("con_3 selected");
      //classTwo.classList.add('class_3');
      break;
    case "con_1":
      alert("con_1 selected");
      //classTwo.classList.remove('class_3', 'class_2');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

// Do the check initially...
checkSelect()
// ... and on change events
myselect.addEventListener('change', checkSelect)
```

```html
<select id="myselect" class="video_home_flex_select">
  <option value="con_1">One</option>
  <option value="con_2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="con_3">Three</option>
</select>
```